# Java File browser

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I am in need of a java file system browser without all the buttons and fields. Does swing have any components that can do this ? If not are there any third party components that can help me with this ?

### JFileChooser

[image]

### What I am looking for

[image]

In hindsight the question is vague. The JList style view of the component is not exactly what I am looking for. I just need a file browser which will fire an event when user selects something. Whether it is a JList style browser or a tree style brower is secondary. I see there are ways I can code this myself, the reason for posting a question here is to see if there are components that do this already.

Comment: what I am looking for == JList(with.Horizontal...), something similair is derived part of JFileChooser

Comment: can't see reason for upvoting this question, voting to close as off-topics

Comment: You might start with the [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7784) and adapt it for your use.

Comment: Thankyou, I see there are ways I can code it myself. But I was hoping to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much yes, you can get the horizontal listing of the files. You will have to use the `JList`'s horizontal wrap for layout orientation. More details about the same can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html).

`JFileChooser` wont allow to hide the rest of the controls, as it will end up loosing the core functionality. You will have to make use of your own custom control using the link described above and do the file operations.